# How to provide a set of values in an either-or situation?

Tags: python, algorithm

I am looking for a cleaner way to write the `lookup_and_url` function. I think there must be a more succinct way to declare and implement my logic. I have done my best to accurately describe the outer function and the inner function within the code itself:

```
def render(opener='corp'):
    """render will render a carousel of videos, with the opener being
    corp or uk and the follower being the other"""

    def lookup_and_url():
        """"lookup_and_url() returns the DOM id and url for the
        opening video (the opener) and the video to follow (the follower).

        It returns a dictionary that allows a loop to make a DOM
        lookup of the id of the HTML element and then replace its
        `src attribute with the provided URL
        """

        src = dict(
            corp='http://www.youtube.com/embed/0lrqEGlu0Fo',
            uk='http://www.youtube.com/embed/30MfCTLhdZ4'
        )

        if opener == 'corp':
            return dict(
                opener = dict(lookup='opener', src=src['corp']),
                follower = dict(lookup='follower', src=src['uk'])
            )
        else:
            return dict(
                opener = dict(lookup='opener', src=src['uk']),
                follower = dict(lookup='follower', src=src['corp'])
            )

    lookup_and_src = lookup_and_url()

    for replace in lookup_and_src:
        root.findmeld(lookup_and_src['lookup']).attributes(src=lookup_and_src['src'])
```

Comment: It can be made shorter, but remember that even if you can write it more concisely it's _perfectly_ clear and explicit right now. Not a single programmer, be they novice or not will have any trouble understanding this piece of code and that's _very_ important. Just because of a piece of code isn't 'clever' doesn't make it bad. I'd probably keep the code the way it is - python favors explicit and clear.

Comment: I don't understand the loop at the end. You don't use the `replace` value you get from the loop, so each time through you do exactly the same things. Also, is there a reason to be using dictionaries everywhere? It seems like you could simply have two variables, and assign them in one order or the other, depending on the function's arguments. But since the loop doesn't make sense, I don't know what that would do, exactly.

Comment: @Blckknght perhaps he meant `root.findmeld(replace['lookup']).attributes(src=replace['src'])`

Comment: @groovy: I though that might be it, but that won't work since the loop is over the keys of the dictionary, not the values (and furthermore, its in an arbitrary order).

Comment: @groovy that's right. Very nice catch Blackknght

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier if you extract the followings into another dictionary (if you have more than 2 entries)?

```
src = {
    'corp': 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/0lrqEGlu0Fo',
    'uk': 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/30MfCTLhdZ4',
}

followers = {
    'corp': 'uk', 
    'uk': 'corp',
}

return {
    'opener': {'lookup': 'opener', 'src': src[opener]},
    'follower': {'lookup': 'follower', 'src': src[followers[opener]]},
}
```

Comment: nice. And I could tighten things up because the dictionary key is the same as the value of `lookup` and just remove `lookup` altogether.

Comment: return dict(
        opener=src[opener],
        follower = src[followers[opener]]
    )

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the only thing that your inner function does is pick which of your two URLs is the "opener" and which is the "follower". All the work you do to build nested dictionaries is pointless. I think you could make this vastly simpler:

```
def render(opener='corp'):
    corp = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/0lrqEGlu0Fo',
    uk = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/30MfCTLhdZ4'

    o, f = (corp, uk) if opener == "corp" else (uk, corp)

    root.findmeld('opener').attributes(src=o)
    root.findmeld('follower').attributes(src=f)
```

This is a lot easier to follow, I think, without all the dictionaries.